# Virtual hosts not working properly in ubuntu LAMP stack

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, lamp

I have created virtual hosts in the following ways:

1. Created laravel.test.conf as

```
 - cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
 - sudo nano laravel.test.conf
```

2. And then updated `laravel.test.conf` as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName laravel.test
    ServerAlias www.laravel.test
    ServerAdmin admin@laravel.test

    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

3. Run command: `sudo a2ensite laravel.test`
4. Permission provided:

```
sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/laravel
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/laravel
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

6. Added sitename on `etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.test www.laravel.test
```

7. Reloaded apache `sudo systemctl reload apache2`
8. Run configtest `sudo apachectl configtest` and received `Syntax Ok`
9. Restarted apache server `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Now, when I hit `larave.test` it loads the site successfully, but when ever I tried to hit any other route then it returns  `404` error as shown in image.

[image]

This app is the freshly installed laravel one with `laravel breeze` so I am pretty much confident that there is a valide route. On top of that, if it was laravel, error, it would have been log it on app level and there would be different UI for 404 pages.

I have checked error log on `laravel/storage/logs` as well as apache2 logs on `var/log/apache2/error.log` but both of these logs file are empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your `rewrite` mod is enabled.

or simply run this in terminal

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite

$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```